# Can a network of linear activation perceptrons model non-linear functions?

Tags: perceptron

I'm confused about whether a network of linear activation perceptrons can model non-linear functions.

According to the book I'm reading (Mitchell), *every* boolean function can be represented by some network of interconnected units based on the [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Definition). This means that XOR, which is non-linear, can be represented by it.

However, later in the book, the author states "multiple layers of cascaded linear units still produce only linear functions", and uses it as motivation to introduce the Sigmoid activation function.

What's going on?

I wonder if the problem is how hidden layers are defined. I understand that if the output of a first perceptron is ∑wi*xi + b, which is then the input of a second perceptron, then the resulting output is still linear, because a linear transformation of a linear transformation is still linear. But the output of a perceptron is 0/1 based on a threshold.

I found an [example](https://medium.com/@stanleydukor/neural-representation-of-and-or-not-xor-and-xnor-logic-gates-perceptron-algorithm-b0275375fea1) on the web that models XOR using a network of linear activations.

This question has been asked before, however, the answers haven't been thorough or specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he means in the book is that a network of perceptrons with non-linear activation functions can solve XOR.
Otherwise you could collapse all the linear operations in the network in a single matrix and you would have a single perceptron capable of solving the XOR problem.

Comment: I wasn't asking/suggesting that a single layer perceptron without an activation function can represent the XOR function. Instead, I was quoting the author of the book I'm reading that "every boolean function can be represented by some network of interconnected units based on the perceptron". And I provided a link to where XOR has been constructed via a network of perceptrons.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you are confused about the network being capable of representing linear functions but the output of it being 0/1?

Comment: No. I'm confused about the conflicting arguments in the book. On one hand, the author says that a _network_ of perceptrons can be constructed to correctly model XOR. Fantastic. But XOR is non-linear. If it is non-linear, then a network of perceptrons can be used to construct something non-linear. Well, that flies against what he says later, which is that a bunch of linear units only output a linear unit.